# Error while communicating with provider Kony fabric

Tags: temenos-quantum

Hi I'm getting this error msg when trying to login for 1st time.Im unable to login but this issue is temporary.after 2 or 1 attempt I'm able to login.
Issue is reproducing intermittently
Can any one help on this

Help on this.Kony quantum fabric

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if the app is being published in Fabric. It could also happen when Kony Public key pinning is set to true but you didn't include a public_keys.json file in Native/Resources with all the public keys of the domains you're trying to access.